# Can't get php-fpm logs into stdout

Tags: php, docker, logging, kubernetes, kibana

**Edit:** Since I'm seeing the downvotes and I understand them, will clarify: The app wasn't logging the standard way and wasn't my call to change that. Also, as a newbie at k8s back then, didn't know how to pick up other files. Devs couldn't change that (can't remember why) but I did manage to pick up the files with something like fluentD/bit. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

I have a pod with 2 containers: nginx and php-fpm.
I'm tyring to get the php-fpm logs (that do log to the container) to stdout so I can see them at kibana.

Here's some info form inside the php-fpm container:

```
#env | grep -i log
APP_LOG_PATH=php://stdout

# php -i | grep -i log
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.17, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
amqp.login => guest => guest
error_log => no value => no value
log_errors => Off => Off
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.log => no value => no value
com_binlog_dump => 0
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
opcache.error_log => no value => no value
opcache.log_verbosity_level => 1 => 1
APP_LOG_PATH => php://stdout
$_SERVER['APP_LOG_PATH'] => php://stdout
$_ENV['APP_LOG_PATH'] => php://stdout
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
#
```

Tried to uncomment this at www.conf (that's where the logs go):

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/www/html/logs/my-app.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

The only thing I could get is related to the process, like "was restarted" "initiated" etc.

I restarted php with:

```
kill -USR2 1
```

But can't get log_errors => on => on after doing that.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Which docker image do you use?

Comment: Hi, we use: php:7.1-fpm-alpine

Comment: Change access.log to `access.log = /proc/self/fd/1` in /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/docker.conf and restart php-fpm instance.

Comment: Just checked and It's already set like that. Maybe it has something to do with the app code that runs in there. I can see the php-fpm log at a random-name.log inside the container, same if I do kubelog pod-name -c fpm, but can't get it out so I can share it via kibana.

Comment: Original is set to 2 (stderr)

Comment: (I edited my previous comment) Here's the docker.conf:
`[global]
error_log = /proc/self/fd/2

[www]
; if we send this to /proc/self/fd/1, it never appears
access.log = /proc/self/fd/1

clear_env = no

; Ensure worker stdout and stderr are sent to the main error log.
catch_workers_output = yes`

Comment: Edit your post for adding php-fpm.conf

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it. that file was already there. I'm new to this, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems something wierd about segmentation fault when you run command`php -i`, Please provide your Dockerfile if possbile.

Comment: It's quite big but mostly doing bash commands to install/set up things. this, at the last RUN modifies the access.log:
`sed -i "s/access.log =.*/access.log = \/proc\/self\/fd\/1/" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/docker.conf`

Answer (score 2):

Set `error_log = /dev/stdout`, `access.log = /dev/stdout`, and `log_level` to which ever level you need in the main php-fpm configuration file. Possibly at `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf` or elsewhere depending on your parent docker image.

[Documentation Reference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php)

Comment: Thank you, will try that and get back to you .

Comment: Still can't, seeing some logs from fpm, but not all of them. I need to see them all, to check what's going go with that app without doing kubectl log or getting inside of it. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you missing the access log? Answer updated to set `access.log` to `/dev/stdout` also.

Comment: When I set access.log = /dev/stdout the fpm container crashes.

Answer (score -4):

turns out, devs needs to change something at the app, related to how it logs.

Once it gets done, I would be able to get the logs thanks to advices here.

Cheers

Comment: What was changed?

Comment: This does not provide a solution to your original question whatsoever.

Comment: It wasn't on our side to fix, it was on dev side.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited the OP. Devs couldn't change the way the app logs but we did manage to pick up custom log files with fluentbit.